# Merge 1000 transparent png files in one

Tags: r, image-processing, imagemagick, bigdata, png

I'm trying to merge (overlaying) ~1000 (12MB total) transparent images *.png in one png or other raster file. Which package or function in R must be use?

The images contains radar cloud data. Evrey day the radar makes ~350 png. 
Sample: [001](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Tom6W.png), [002](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XK299.png), [003](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UnMS9.png), [004](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BfIzc.png)

Here is the legend of colors [legend](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rJ8MF.png)

After that i will compare the result with data from 120 rain gauges.

Now i use this code

```
library(base)
library(png)

homeserverDir = "S:/R/radarTEST"
dDir_new = paste(homeserverDir, "dd_stack", sep = "/")
rr_dir = paste(homeserverDir, "dd_stackD", sep = "/")

setwd(dDir_new)
filenames <- list.files(path = dDir_new, pattern="*.png")
theATs <- lapply(filenames, raster)

STACK1 <- stack(theATs)

res <- Reduce("+", theATs, accumulate = TRUE)

setwd(rr_dir)

lapply(seq_along(res), function(x) {
  writeRaster(res[[x]], paste(filenames[x], "_cumsum", sep = ""), datatype = 'FLT4S', overwrite = TRUE)
})


Grids_list = list.files(rr_dir, "grd")
Radar_sum = raster(Grids_list[length(Grids_list)])

plot(Radar_sum)
```

Comment: [magick](https://docs.ropensci.org/magick/) is nice

Comment: See the link for magick above or rmagick at https://github.com/rmagick/rmagick. Use the flatten command.

Comment: Maybe provide 3-4 images so we can show you how. Also, please say what OS you use.

Comment: I was make changes to question. OS - Windows 10.